# How to handle an empty date string in JSONDecoder

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, jsondecoder

The date parameter in my json can be empty(""). How to handle it in JSONDecoder?

The custom dateDecodingStrategy can only handle different format, but can't handle an empty value.(The date which formatter returned can't be optional).

When the date have an value, it will work perfectly. But when the date is "", it will crash.

```
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom({ (decoder) -> Date in
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
        if let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr) {
            return date
        }
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        if let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr) {
            return date
        }
        throw DateError.invalidDate
    })
```

Comment: What date do you expect to return if the string is empty? By the way blame the owner of the web service to send consistent data.

Comment: When the string is empty, I expect to return nil. The date parameter in my struct is optional (date: Date?).

Comment: Then you have to decode the date directly in the struct by adding a custom initializer or decode the date as `String` and add a computed property in the struct. `dateDecodingStrategy` is for consistent data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @vadian's comment, and supposing you are expecting user related data with a date of birth (dob) that may or may not have been declared by a certain user, what I did was the following

```
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    //init other properties...
    do {
        self.dob = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .dob)
    } catch {
        self.dob = nil
    }
}
```

But again as per @vadian's comment, it would be better if the dob wasn't returned in the JSON response. That way you wouldn't need the do/catch blocks at all.